# Database Index confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

I've been trying to figure out this answer for a couple answer now, but can't seem to wrap my head around it. Can anyone explain to me how these answers are calculate? I know that: A = 1000, B = 20, C = 10, D = 10 and E = 1. I understand that when there is no Index, we have to search 50 X 20 because we need to go through all the sensorID(50) and all the times (20 for each). Then when we put an Index on sensorID, we only have to search through the times. I mainly get lost when we put an index on time and it drops it down to 10. Shouldn't it be 50?

[image]

Comment: Read this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/ It will help you understand this very important corner of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> *I mainly get lost when we put an index on time and it drops it down to 10. Shouldn't it be 50?*

Read the question again carefully:

> ... there are exactly **10** readings for every unique time...

This means that after 1 index seek operation (which you don't need to take into account as it said in the question) the database engine have to traverse only 10 rows (tuples), applying the filter on `sensorID` to find the target record.

Comment: So why are those 10 tuples ignores when we do the original query with no Index? We only use 50 * 20. Shouldn't we use 50 * 20 * 10?

Comment: Index on the time column has in it's leaf nodes pointers (PK values) to unique rows having the same time value. Therefore the db engine need to go only through these ten rows to find the one it needs. To better understand this read up on btree structures that indices usually use.

Answer (score 0):

You have two clauses of "column = constant" AND'd together in the `WHERE` clause.  The "best" INDEX is a composite index on the two columns.  That is, `INDEX(sensorID, time)`.  The order of the two columns does not matter for the query you presented, but if you had `WHERE sensorID=123 AND time BETWEEN ...`, then that order is definitely better.  Further discussion in [my index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

The number of "probes" is one (to find the first index entry for the given sensorID and time (or start of time)), plus it will linearly scan the INDEX to find any more rows with the same sensorID *and* time in the given range.  Hence, it is optimal.

(I would be interested to hear if you get more out of the 'luke' link, or my link.)